# Менять местами элементы динамического списка

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, односвязный-список

Нужно поменять местами второй и третий элемент списка. Программа уже меняет первый и последний. Нужна помощь.

````
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[10];
    int V, power;
    char country[20];
}struc;

typedef struct Node {
    struc A;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;
Node* create(struc x);

void back(Node** p, struc x);

void prin(Node* p);

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int A = 1, i = 1;
    Node* p = 0;
    struc x, y;
    Node* head = 0;

    while (A != 0)
    {
        printf("Мотоцикл №%d\n", i);
        printf("Введите название %d-го мотоцикла: ", i);
        scanf("%s", &x.name);
        if (x.name[0] == '*') break;
        printf("Введите объем двигателя для %d-го мотоцикла: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &x.V);
        printf("Введите лошадиные силы для %d-го мотоцикла: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &x.power);
        printf("Введите страну изготовителя %d-го мотоцикла: ", i);
        scanf("%s", &x.country);
        printf("\n");
        if (A == 1)
        {
            p = create(x);
            head = p;
            A += 1;
        }
        else back(&p, x);
        i++;
    }
    prin(p);

    y = p->A;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->next == NULL) {
            x = p->A;
            p->A = y;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    p = head;
    p->A = x;
    prin(p);
}
Node* create(struc x) {
    Node* t = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    t->A = x;
    t->next = NULL;
    return t;
}
void back(Node** p, struc x) {
    Node* NEWe = create(x);
    Node* tpm = *p;
    while (tpm->next != NULL) {
        tpm = tpm->next;
    }
    tpm->next = NEWe;
}
void prin(Node* p) {
    int i = 1;
    printf("+---------------------------------------------------------+\n"
        "|   |               |   характеристики   |                |\n"
        "| № |    Название   |----------+---------|     страна     |\n"
        "|   |               |   обьём  |   л.с   |                |\n"
        "+---+---------------+----------+---------+----------------+\n");
    while (p != NULL) {

        printf("| %-2d| %-14s| %-9d| %-8d| %-15s|\n", i, p->A.name, p->A.V, p->A.power, p->A.country);
        printf("+---------------------------------------------------------+\n");
        p = p->next;
        i++;
    }
    getch();
}```
````

Comment: Ну так же как и первый с последним меняли. Находите второй узел, запоминаете указатель. Находите третий узел, запоминаете указатель. Меняете значения у указателей так же, как у первого и последнего.

Comment: Чтобы при вводе не пробегать каждый раз весь список в функции `back()`, можно либо добавлять элемент в начало, или создать структуру для списка и хранить указатели и на начало и на конец списка `struct MyList {Node *head, *tail;}`